# React Navigation error. Navigation prop not see in screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm attempting to add navigation to my screen using the class component syntax.

I've got 2 screens currently in a stack navigator. Inside of my 1st screen(Profile) I have a button that I want to use to trigger the other screen.

I'm getting a "The title of a prop must be a string" error. I assume the navigation prop should already be present, and it loads just fine and works when I replace the navigation statement with a test action.

Below I've included the main App.js, which has my stack declaration, followed by the profile.js which has the button in question in the render. I've also included my dependancies from my package.json. A live version can be seen here <snack.expo.dev/ERocq68UX>

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Profile Page'>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Bathroom" component={BathroomSelectionScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View} from 'react-native';


class ProfileScreen extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    }

    render() {
    return (
    <View >
 
    <Text>Bathroom</Text>
    <Button title="Press me" onPress = { () =>{this.props.navigation.navigate("Bathroom")}}></Button>

   
        </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ProfileScreen;
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1"
  }
```

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: Please edit the post to include the actual error message, the complete error, as a formatted and readable snippet. Please also try to include the code stacktrace if you can, as well as all the relevant code enough to be considered a [mcve] so we can see what it's doing and why any errors are thrown.

Comment: @DrewReese I just added some more details. I couldn't easily include the stacktrace, but the error was just the Statement included above. I think this should be sufficient, but if not, I'll adjust. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What title is the error in reference to? I see a `title` prop on the `Button` component. I've never seen nor heard of any "title of a prop", what line of code is the issue on? Can you indicate in your code where? Think you could create a *running* [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could take a look at live?

Comment: I would guess there is something under the hood with the navigation.navigate method, if you were to replace this.props.navigation.navigate("Bathroom") with alert("test") everything behaves as expected.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce any errors or other issues with this code. Here's an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/react-navigation-error-navigation-prop-not-see-in-screen). It works in all the simulators and on my android device.

Comment: so the only difference between our declarations is I made my screens seperate files. Here is a link to my snack, try to run on android or ios https://snack.expo.dev/ERocq68UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `Button` components in `BathroomSelectionScreen` are missing a `title` prop. The `Button`'s "labels" are specified on a `title` prop, not as children.

Additionally the `navigation` needs to be accessed from the `this.props` object.

```
class BathroomSelectionScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button // <-- missing title prop
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate({ // <-- navigation undeclared
              name: "Home",
              params: { BathroomSelection: "Men" },
              merge: true
            })
          }
        >
          Men's Restroom
        </Button>
        <Button // <-- missing title prop
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate({ // <-- navigation undeclared
              name: "Home",
              params: { BathroomSelection: "Women" },
              merge: true
            })
          }
        >
          Women's Restroom
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## Solution

Move the button text to the `title` prop and fix the `navigation` object access from the `props` object.

Example:

```
class BathroomSelectionScreen extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate({
            name: 'Home',
            params: { BathroomSelection: 'Men' },
            merge: true
          })}
          title="Men's Restroom"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate({
            name: 'Home',
            params: { BathroomSelection: 'Women' },
            merge: true
          })}
          title="Women's Restroom"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```